# There is no problem in code but the output is nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net

how are you,sir my code is correct means there is no error after debugging that code.My goal is that if the user click on button(which is placed in default.aspx,for example)then the database table is created in database(database placed within sql express),I write the code for that purpose we debug the code and there is no error in the code .when i click the button(in runtime).when i check the database(which is in the sql express)there is no  table is created in that database.please sir solve my problem.The code written in c# behind the button is that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
//using PractiseWeb.DataSet1TableAdapters;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using ADOX;
using ADODB;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  SqlConnection conn;
  SqlCommand cmd;
  string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gameConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }

  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    try
    {
      conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
      if (!(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open))
      {
        conn.Open();
      }
      string sql = "CREATE TABLE mySchoolRecord(StudentId INTEGER CONSTRAINT PkeyMyId PRIMARY KEY, Name CHAR(50)," + "Address CHAR(255)," + "Contact INTEGER));";
      cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      sql = "INSERT INTO mySchoolRecord (StudentId, Name,Address,Contact) VALUES (1, 'Mr. Manish', " + " 'Sector-12,Noida', 2447658  );";
      cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      sql = "INSERT INTO mySchoolRecord (StudentId, Name,Address,Contact) VALUES (2, 'Mr. Ravi', " + " 'New Delhi', 2584076521   );";
      cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      sql = "INSERT INTO mySchoolRecord (StudentId, Name,Address,Contact) VALUES (3, 'Mr. Peter', " + " 'United States', 25684124  );";
      cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


      if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
      {
        conn.Close();
      }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }

  }
}
```

THANKS SIR

Comment: Please edit your question. Add "code" format for your code

Comment: can you copy your sql and paste on sqlserver directly and see if it creating or not?? do a break on exception while debuggin ,it will tell you if there are any exceptions in the code.

Comment: Saying "there is no problem in code" is ... odd. 99% of the time, the problem is in our own code...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the try-catch and see what's happening. Writing to the console isn't going to help much in an ASP.NET app. :)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  SqlConnection conn;
  SqlCommand cmd;
  string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gameConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    using (conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
      if (!(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open))
      {
        conn.Open();
      }
      string sql = "CREATE TABLE mySchoolRecord(StudentId INTEGER CONSTRAINT PkeyMyId PRIMARY KEY, Name CHAR(50)," + "Address CHAR(255)," + "Contact INTEGER));";
      cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      sql = "INSERT INTO mySchoolRecord (StudentId, Name,Address,Contact) VALUES (1, 'Mr. Manish', " + " 'Sector-12,Noida', 2447658  );";
      cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      sql = "INSERT INTO mySchoolRecord (StudentId, Name,Address,Contact) VALUES (2, 'Mr. Ravi', " + " 'New Delhi', 2584076521   );";
      cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      sql = "INSERT INTO mySchoolRecord (StudentId, Name,Address,Contact) VALUES (3, 'Mr. Peter', " + " 'United States', 25684124  );";
      cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
      {
        conn.Close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@sayyer ,

follow the below steps
1)can you copy your sql and paste on sqlserver directly and see if it creating or not?? do a break on exception while debuggin ,it will tell you if there are any exceptions in the code

2) Check your database connection

3) check all the formating for the insert statements.

Best way to fix the issue is do ctr + alt + E and check break on exceptions, that will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try removing semicolons from SQL queries.